# What does #### (four hashtags) in R mean?

Tags: rstudio

E.g., when I want to set different parts of all code using "####", but it only displays untitled for each part in Rstudio. Why?

Comment: You have to be more clear, please edit the question with an example of the problem. You want to *separate* code parts with four `#`?

Answer (score 5):

You can use this to organize your code. Try

```
#### Title ####
```

This way you can name parts of your code and jump right there. See here:

[image: Preview]

Further, if you use...

```
 #####
 some code
 .....
 #####
```

... you can hide the code between the five #

Comment: Here's the relevant rstudio.com link and quote ["To insert a new code section you can use the Code -> Insert Section command. Alternatively, any comment line which includes at least four trailing dashes (-), equal signs (=), or pound signs (#) automatically creates a code section."](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200484568-Code-Folding-and-Sections)

Comment: @IceCreamToucan Any chance that you know if there is a way to make subsections? Like Title A (sub1), Title A (sub2), Title B, ...

Comment: As far as I know, nested code folding is not possible in Rstudio except for Rmarkdown documents and function definitions / if-else structures

Comment: @IceCreamToucan I was afraid this is the case. I've looked for it some times but wasn't able to find anything. Thanks anyway for the source!